# vba chart copy from one sheet to another. (wish to use sheet index reference instead of name)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie in VBA. I have created a column chart in sheet 1 and want to move it to sheet 2.

I'm trying to use sheet index as reference but not a specific names.

I have come up with some codes and the part starting with `activesheet.chartobjects.select` (6th last line) is where problems start ...

Please help and I really appreciate the help and kindness here.

```
Option Explicit

Sub createClusteredBarChart()
    Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
    Dim mysourcedata As Range
    Dim mychart As Chart
    Dim mychartdestination As Range

    Set myworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sales figures")

    With myworksheet
        Set mysourcedata = .Range("a1:f6")

        Set mychartdestination = .Range("A2:z10")

        Set mychart = .Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType:=xlColumnClustered, _
            Left:=mychartdestination.Cells(1).Left, Top:=mychartdestination.Cells(1).Top, _
            Width:=mychartdestination.Width, Height:=mychartdestination.Height).Chart

        With mychart
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 16000000
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 4000000
            .ChartArea.Select
            .ChartArea.Height = 216
            .ChartArea.Width = 360
            .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 65 
        End With

        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet18").Range("a1").Paste
    End With

    mychart.SetSourceData Source:=mysourcedata    
End Sub
```

Comment: Worksheets(IndexNumber) is not a reliable method of identifying sheets.  If you have Worksheet("sales figures") that name takes some effort to change.  If the name is changed, code that attempts to access this sheet will fail.

Comment: The index number depends on the sequence of the tabs.  The sequence is easy to change by accidentally clicking on a tag and dragging it left or right.  Or perhaps the user will deliberately change the sequence to something they think is more sensible not realising that they should not.  If the sequence is changed there will still be a Worksheets(2), say, but it will not be the worksheet the macro expects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

Remarks:

1. Read code's comments
2. Check that I have reordered some lines to make the "With objects" more readable

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub createClusteredBarChart()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
    Dim mysourcedata As Range
    Dim mychart As Chart
    Dim mychartdestination As Range

    ' Set source worksheet
    Set myworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sales figures")

    With myworksheet
        ' Set source data
        Set mysourcedata = .Range("a1:f6")

        ' Set destination range
        Set mychartdestination = .Range("A2:z10")

        ' Create blank chart
        Set mychart = .Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType:=xlColumnClustered, _
        Left:=mychartdestination.Cells(1).Left, Top:=mychartdestination.Cells(1).Top, _
        Width:=mychartdestination.Width, Height:=mychartdestination.Height).Chart
    End With

    ' Adjust chart's settings
    With mychart
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 16000000
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 4000000
        .ChartArea.Select
        .ChartArea.Height = 216
        .ChartArea.Width = 360
        .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 65

        ' Set chart's source data
        .SetSourceData Source:=mysourcedata

    End With

    ' This line will move the chart to another worksheet (in this example sheet index = 2) (be careful when you have hidden sheets)
    mychart.Location xlLocationAsObject, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Copy method is not supported for chart objects embedded on a worksheet, only for chart sheets (charts held in their own sheet). You have to copy it as a Shape

So replace

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet18").Range("a1").Paste
```

With

```
   myworksheet.shapes(1).copy  'assuming it's the only object on the sheet
   Sheets("Sheet18").Range("a1").PasteSpecial
```